# expected value for a cylindrical distribution function

Tags: statistics

How can I calculate the mean of $$\rho(r,z)=\frac{N}{(2Pi)^{(3/2)}\sigma_z\sigma_r^2}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2\sigma_z^2})\exp(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma_r^2})$$

Some background:
It is a particle density. The first gaussian distribution gives transverse profile and the second one gives the axial profile. $r$ is the distance from the center point.
In generel, the mean $E(x)$ is defined by $$E(X)=\int xf(x)\text{d}x$$ But here I have two variables? I found the equation $$E(g(X,Y))=\int\int g(x,y)f(x,y)\text{d}x\text{d}y$$
and $g(x,y)$ is a function of the expected value. So it is just $g(x,y)=xy$ ? Then $$E(rz)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{N}{(2Pi)^{(3/2)}\sigma_z\sigma_r^2}\exp(-\frac{z^2}{2\sigma_z^2})\exp(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma_r^2})r^2z\text{d}r\text{d}z\text{d}\theta$$
which is zero. So it cannot be correct.

thanks, Benny

To make things clear (edited):

$N$ is the amount of particles and the dimensions of $\sigma_z,\sigma_r,z,r$ are lengths. Therefore the unit of $\rho$ is [particles/$m^3$]. So, the average should be the same unit. $\int \int \int \rho r\text{d}r\text{d}z\text{d}\theta$ is equal to $N$.
Also a shift parameter can be added $$\rho(r,z)=\frac{N}{(2Pi)^{(3/2)}\sigma_z\sigma_r^2}\exp(-\frac{(z-z_0)^2}{2\sigma_z^2})\exp(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma_r^2})$$ Than $$E(rz)=N\sqrt{\pi/2}z0\sigma_r$$
Now the unit is [particles$~m^2$]. Why did the unit change?
A correlated question: Why is the mean of $$E(r)=\int\int\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_r}\exp(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma_r^2})r^2\text{d}r\text{d}\theta=\sqrt{\pi/2}\sigma_r$$
I would have assumed $E(r)=0$. The 3D bell curve has a rotational invarianc and is thus independent of $\theta$. I hope that I was able to clear up some questions. Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: Why can't the expectation be zero? Expectations are zero all the time. It's unclear what quantity you actually want the expectation of though. Also, I think you have a typo in your first equation.

Comment: The typo that @spaceisdarkgreen mentions is that ${N}\over{{(2\pi)^(3/2)} \sigma_z \sigma^2_r}$ should be $1\over{2\pi \sigma_z \sigma_r}$.  If so, that means what you have is the product of two normal density functions meaning that $r$ and $z$ are independent normal random variables.  And do you mean "particle density" rather than "partical density" ?  What is $N$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen. That makes sense.  I also would have expected an "angle" ($\theta$) in the joint density function because of the word "cylindrical" and "axial".  (But I know nothing about the physics of what is being described.)

Comment: @JimB I doubt $r$ and $z$ are independent normals, since $r$ must be nonnegative. I would guess the physical situation is that $x,y,z$ are independent normals and $x$ and $y$ have the same variance. That would mean there needs to be an $r\sin\theta$ out front in the joint PDF of $r,\theta,z,$ or an $r$ out front of the joint PDF of $r,z.$ If OP is using the latter they should not be integrating over $\theta$ at the end. Either way, the normalization is off and they need to clarify what they want to calculate.. $E(RZ)=0$ is true but doubt it's what they actually want.

Comment: @JimB deleted and rewrote earlier comment but I think the new version addresses the angle issue

Comment: @JimB actually no $\sin\theta$ in the one, was mixing up with spherical.

Comment: Thank you for every comment, it helps a lot. I edited my question. Eventually, I want to calculate the average density within a certain range of $r$.